# AWS solution for processing many API calls in parallel

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

We are preparing solution for gathering data from one of our analysis web portal, we are collecting data using Python/API calls. CSV/XLSX report from our analysis web tool pulling lots of JSON data via Python script using mentioned API Calls. We need to get data for large number of customers. We have executed our Python script from AWS t2.medium VM, 4 GB RAM, 2 CPUs. Script runs around 2-3 hours to build the CSV/XLSX report depending on the query (it takes too long for us). So we are thinking about other solution, we need to speed up CSV/XLSX report generation. We are not sure what components we can use in AWS. We are considering: one main Lambda function (authentication, work distribution, triggering concurrent Lambda functions) and many concurrent Lambda functions. Each concurrent Lambda will be responsible for part of the work (10% of the clients, 10% of the API calls). Is there any tool we can use to speed up mentioned solution in AWS, Step Functions/Parallel flows, Lambda?

My Sequence creator (main Lambda function) code looks like below:

```
import boto3
import json
import requests

client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response1 = client.invoke(FunctionName="worker-00", InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event));
    response2 = client.invoke(FunctionName="worker-01", InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event));
    response3 = client.invoke(FunctionName="worker-02", InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event));
    response4 = client.invoke(FunctionName="worker-03", InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(event));
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about this line `Each concurrent Lambda will be responsible for part of the work (10% of the clients, 10% of the API calls)`, since lambdas should be responsible for a single task only.

Comment: For example, If we have 100 customers, and we need to gather data for all 100 customers. We can use 5 Lambdas, make them to work parallelly, 20 customers per lambda, is should speed up the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that output file will be big and it is not streaming data then,

For your approach Fan-out pattern which you already mentioned will be great, ranging from **N customers per lambda** to the fastest **1 customer per lambda**, with a pattern of **1-N-S3-1** which will be the fastest but with a higher cost too,

**Sequence merger** lambda will be triggered by cloudwatch every **x minutes** where **x** is the average running time of all lambdas in minutes.
As soon as all sequences are present, it will merge them to a single file and you can save that output in another S3 bucket and remove all the existing sequences in the Sequence bucket.

Note: Adding **aws step functions** in this design can be a good alternative with improved control but will affect the price a lot.

[image]

The above diagram will behave something like the below diagram when we call lambdas asynchronously

[image]

You can also tune the memory required for your task to improve performance using https://github.com/alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning

**Edit:**

The sequence creator code should look something like the below sample code-->
Here is a sample code:

```
workers = 3
payload = [{"payload1":"1"},{"payload2":"2"},{"payload3":"3"}]
for i in range(workers):
    lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName='sequence',InvocationType='Event',Payload=json.dumps(workers_payload[i]))
```

Comment: Ok, and what wilk be the role od the Sequence creator block?

Comment: Suppose,
You have 100 customers,
You are fetching data for each customer from a single endpoint using their name.

Then this function will call the async lambda function 100 times with payload as customer name and endpoint.
And 100 lambda functions will run parallely.

If you are fetching data for each customer using different endoints, 1 for each customer,
Then you need to call async lambda 100 time with payload as their respective endpoint for each customer. 
And 100 lambda functions will run parallely.

Comment: @tester81 The sequence 1,2,3 are just N, they can be increase as well as decreased based on the number of sets you want to create using sequence creator function,

Comment: Thx a lot, and one question, how should I run concurrent lambda functions from Sequence creator lambda function. I am using in my main Sequence creator lambda 'response = client.invoke(FunctionName=''string' , InvocationType'RequestResponse')', but I am not sure if the functions run in parallel.

Comment: I have added my `Sequence creator` Lambda code above in main post. I have looked into cloud watch logs, and the `worker` lambda functions are not running in parallel.

Comment: @tester81 I added some sample code, the reason in diagram I used 3 lambda functions because I wanted to explain how calling will work parallely, that was a scenario for 3 functions. for async calls you can call them in a loop and assign the payload in array and number of workers required to call other lambda

Comment: @tester81 I added 1 more diagram for better understanding